# How to change CSS to SASS with the gatsby plugin?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to change my CSS to SASS. To achieve this I have installed the gatsby-plugin-sass, but whenever I execute it I receive an error. How can I fix this error?

This is how my gatsby-config.js looks like after installing the gatsby-plugin-sass:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    'gatsby-transformer-remark'
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
}
```

And this is how I am trying to use sass code:

```
$font-stack : Roboto;
$primary-color : 'orange';

h1{
  font-family: $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color
}
```

The error I receive is the following:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> $font-stack : Roboto;  
| $primary-color : 'orange';  
|
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I think you mean sass to css :see_no_evil:

Comment: have you imported the font ? @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap'); if importing it locally the file imports need to be relative to the entry scss file.

Comment: have you installed gatsby-plugin-sass and node-sass?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri already install the gatsby-plugin-sass